# Ubuntu 13.10 wireshark crashes at start of capture with segfault unless ran as root

Tags: 13.10, crash, segmentation-fault, wireshark

Wireshark has always worked without issue for me, but upon using it on `13.10` I find that as soon as I start a live capture it does nothing, the screen dims, then it crashes.

`syslog` shows:

```
wireshark[5616]: segfault at 7fffbc3a3ff8 ip 00007fa83f334284 sp
00007fffbc3a3ff0 error 6 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.3800.1[7fa83f324000+4f000]
```

If I run wireshark as root, this segfault does not seem to happen. In the past I have always followed the steps [here](http://www.dickson.me.uk/2012/09/17/installing-wireshark-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/) to set various permissions and capabilities to allow wireshark to run as normal user. Do these need to change for 13.10?

My wireshark version is from the repos: `wireshark 1.10.2 (SVN Rev 51934 from /trunk-1.10)`

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After attempting to run wireshark from terminal and collecting a log:

```
wireshark &> out.log
```

the log was filled with things like

```
(wireshark:6087): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkScrollbar'

(wireshark:6087): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'GtkWidget'

.
.
.
```

Upon googling these I came across [bug1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireshark/+bug/1248400) and [bug2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireshark/+bug/1208583), and the solution posted there:

```
export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
wireshark
```

got wireshark running for me.

....................................*ASIDE*....................................

Quite strange really, as I hate overlay scrollbars and have disabled them anyway, with the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface ubuntu-overlay-scrollbars false
```

and they don't appear on any of my other applications (e.g. firefox or the terminal), so strange that `wireshark` is snagging on them.

Also strange that root didn't have issues.

................................................................................

Comment: Worked for me in 14.04 for this error in syslog: wireshark[6878]: segfault at 7fff0f996fe8 ip 00007fa9d0297c95 sp 00007fff0f996fe0 error 6 in libc-2.19.so[7fa9d0218000+1bb000]

Answer (score 1):

Just like fpghost said the solution is to make the commands:

```
$ export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0
$ wireshark
```

If you want to execute from the Wireshark application icon just replace the `Exec=` line in the application launcher file at `/usr/share/applications/wireshark.desktop` with this one:

```
Exec=bash -i -c "export LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 && wireshark" %f
```